# Ubuntu Server crashing inside virtualbox

Tags: server, virtualbox

I am running a Ubuntu Server guest on a Windows 10 host in Virtualbox.

- 2048MB Ram (host has 32GB)
- 4 CPUs (host has 4 cores, 8 threads)
- PAE/NX, VT-x/AMD-V enabled
- 128MB VRAM
- 10GB VDI disk
- Bridged IntelPRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter

I am mostly running rtorrent through openvpn, downloading to mounted windows smb shares. using apache to communicate between rutorrent and rtorrent. everything is working fine so far, but I am crashing every hour or so, and this time I had top running and it outputted me the following messege when it crashed:

```
Message from syslogd@ubuntuserver at Jul  2 17:01:21 ...
 kernel:[ 7706.657113] usercopy: Kernel memory exposure attempt detected from SLUB object 'vm_area_struct(1985:init.scope)' (offset 45, size 187)!
```

I am not an expert in the least in Linux so any help would greatly appreciated.

I have searched /var/log/kern.log for all occurences or "exposure" so hopefully these are the relevant log files:

```
19123 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238850] ------------[ cut here ]------------
19124 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238853] Bad or missing usercopy whitelist? Kernel memory exposure attempt detected from SLUB object 'TCP(1226:apache2.service)' (offset 19, size 98)!
19125 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238884] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 5704 at mm/usercopy.c:75 usercopy_warn+0x81/0xa0
19126 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238884] Modules linked in: md4 cmac nls_utf8 cifs libarc4 fscache libdes xt_statistic xt_set ipt_rpfilter xt_multiport iptable_raw ip_set_hash_ip ip_set_hash_net ip_set vxlan ip6_udp_tun>
19127 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238943]  raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_generic usbhid hid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel vmwgfx aesni_intel crypto_simd ttm cryptd drm_kms_helper>
19128 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238956] CPU: 0 PID: 5704 Comm: openvpn Tainted: G           O      5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu
19129 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238957] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
19130 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238959] RIP: 0010:usercopy_warn+0x81/0xa0
19131 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238961] Code: 58 89 41 51 49 89 c0 49 c7 c2 19 47 57 89 49 89 f1 48 89 f9 4c 0f 45 d2 48 c7 c7 08 7a 58 89 4c 89 da 4c 89 d6 e8 b1 b1 7b 00 <0f> 0b 48 83 c4 18 c9 c3 48 c7 c6 ba 8e 5a 89>
19132 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238961] RSP: 0018:ffffb51a426d7c18 EFLAGS: 00010286
19133 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238962] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000062 RCX: 0000000000000006
19134 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238963] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: ffff982b3da178c0
19135 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238964] RBP: ffffb51a426d7c30 R08: 00000000000002ab R09: 0000000000000004
19136 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238964] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff982b3bc00013
19137 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238965] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffff982b3bc00075 R15: 0000000000000000
19138 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238966] FS:  00007f68cc179cc0(0000) GS:ffff982b3da00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
19139 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238967] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
19140 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238967] CR2: 00007f0745d20000 CR3: 000000007178a003 CR4: 00000000000606f0
19141 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238971] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
19142 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238972] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
19143 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238973] Call Trace:
19144 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238977]  __check_heap_object+0xb1/0x120
19145 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238978]  __check_object_size+0x13f/0x150
19146 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238980]  simple_copy_to_iter+0x2b/0x50
19147 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238981]  __skb_datagram_iter+0x19d/0x2d0
19148 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238983]  ? __skb_wait_for_more_packets+0x170/0x170
19149 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238984]  skb_copy_datagram_iter+0x40/0x90
19150 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238987]  tun_do_read+0x48e/0x680
19151 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238989]  ? wake_up_q+0x70/0x70
19152 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238991]  tun_chr_read_iter+0x5b/0xa0
19153 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238993]  new_sync_read+0x122/0x1b0
19154 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238995]  __vfs_read+0x29/0x40
19155 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238996]  vfs_read+0xab/0x160
19156 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238997]  ksys_read+0x67/0xe0
19157 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.238999]  __x64_sys_read+0x1a/0x20
19158 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239001]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
19159 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239003]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
19160 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239005] RIP: 0033:0x7f68cc938332
19161 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239006] Code: 9c 00 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb be 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 56 c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 48>
19162 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239007] RSP: 002b:00007ffc31a8d218 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
19163 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239008] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffc31a8d270 RCX: 00007f68cc938332
19164 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239008] RDX: 00000000000005fc RSI: 000055d5f9a845a8 RDI: 0000000000000004
19165 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239009] RBP: 00007ffc31a8d270 R08: 00000000000005fc R09: 000000000000000a
19166 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239009] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000002
19167 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239010] R13: 000055d5f80f2540 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
19168 Jul  2 09:11:23 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 1098.239012] ---[ end trace 92f904c7680db778 ]---

19828 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642191] ------------[ cut here ]------------
19829 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642193] Bad or missing usercopy whitelist? Kernel memory exposure attempt detected from SLUB object 'task_struct(1842:session-5.scope)' (offset 554, size 238)!
19830 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642200] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 3580 at mm/usercopy.c:75 usercopy_warn+0x81/0xa0
19831 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642200] Modules linked in: vxlan ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel ipt_rpfilter xt_set xt_multiport iptable_raw ip_set_hash_net ip_set_hash_ip ip_set veth md4 cmac nls_utf8 cifs libarc4 fscache >
19832 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642235]  raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_generic usbhid hid vmwgfx crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ttm ghash_clmulni_intel drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops aes>
19833 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642245] CPU: 0 PID: 3580 Comm: openvpn Tainted: G           O      5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu
19834 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642246] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
19835 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642248] RIP: 0010:usercopy_warn+0x81/0xa0
19836 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642249] Code: b8 b9 41 51 49 89 c0 49 c7 c2 19 47 b7 b9 49 89 f1 48 89 f9 4c 0f 45 d2 48 c7 c7 08 7a b8 b9 4c 89 da 4c 89 d6 e8 b1 b1 7b 00 <0f> 0b 48 83 c4 18 c9 c3 48 c7 c6 ba 8e ba b9>
19837 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642250] RSP: 0018:ffffb31a82c1fc18 EFLAGS: 00010286
19838 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642250] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00000000000000ee RCX: 0000000000000006
19839 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642251] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: ffff8fe0bda178c0
19840 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642252] RBP: ffffb31a82c1fc30 R08: 00000000000002af R09: 0000000000000004
19841 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642252] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff8fe043a2022a
19842 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642253] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffff8fe043a20318 R15: 0000000000000000
19843 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642253] FS:  00007f26876f9cc0(0000) GS:ffff8fe0bda00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
19844 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642254] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
19845 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642255] CR2: 00007f4b856cb000 CR3: 0000000071652006 CR4: 00000000000606f0
19846 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642257] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
19847 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642258] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
19848 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642258] Call Trace:
19849 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642261]  __check_heap_object+0xb1/0x120
19850 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642263]  __check_object_size+0x13f/0x150
19851 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642264]  simple_copy_to_iter+0x2b/0x50
19852 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642266]  __skb_datagram_iter+0x19d/0x2d0
19853 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642267]  ? __skb_wait_for_more_packets+0x170/0x170
19854 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642268]  skb_copy_datagram_iter+0x40/0x90
19855 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642270]  tun_do_read+0x48e/0x680
19856 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642271]  ? wake_up_q+0x70/0x70
19857 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642273]  tun_chr_read_iter+0x5b/0xa0
19858 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642274]  new_sync_read+0x122/0x1b0
19859 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642276]  __vfs_read+0x29/0x40
19860 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642277]  vfs_read+0xab/0x160
19861 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642278]  ksys_read+0x67/0xe0
19862 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642279]  __x64_sys_read+0x1a/0x20
19863 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642281]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
19864 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642283]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
19865 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642284] RIP: 0033:0x7f2687eb8332
19866 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642285] Code: 9c 00 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb be 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 56 c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 48>
19867 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642286] RSP: 002b:00007ffcb7f37ca8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
19868 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642286] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffcb7f37d00 RCX: 00007f2687eb8332
19869 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642287] RDX: 00000000000005fc RSI: 000056282b8a45a8 RDI: 0000000000000004
19870 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642287] RBP: 00007ffcb7f37d00 R08: 00000000000005fc R09: 000000000000000a
19871 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642288] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000002
19872 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642288] R13: 000056282b143540 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
19873 Jul  2 10:05:18 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2198.642290] ---[ end trace bf50f5c8147884f1 ]---

23598 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365633] ------------[ cut here ]------------
23599 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365636] Bad or missing usercopy whitelist? Kernel memory exposure attempt detected from SLUB object 'files_cache(1779:f9ddcba6cfabfe4ef6ec2b1f746ce546011ed403745e465e75a235411c0ef918)' (>
23600 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365657] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 7279 at mm/usercopy.c:75 usercopy_warn+0x81/0xa0
23601 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365657] Modules linked in: msr vxlan ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel xt_set ipt_rpfilter xt_multiport iptable_raw ip_set_hash_net ip_set_hash_ip ip_set veth xt_statistic xt_nat xt_tcpudp xt_ma>
23602 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365697]  raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_generic usbhid hid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel vmwgfx ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimg>
23603 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365708] CPU: 0 PID: 7279 Comm: openvpn Tainted: G           O      5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu
23604 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365708] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
23605 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365710] RIP: 0010:usercopy_warn+0x81/0xa0
23606 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365711] Code: 98 88 41 51 49 89 c0 49 c7 c2 19 47 97 88 49 89 f1 48 89 f9 4c 0f 45 d2 48 c7 c7 08 7a 98 88 4c 89 da 4c 89 d6 e8 b1 b1 7b 00 <0f> 0b 48 83 c4 18 c9 c3 48 c7 c6 ba 8e 9a 88>
23607 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365712] RSP: 0018:ffffb77bc2c0fc18 EFLAGS: 00010286
23608 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365713] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000030 RCX: 0000000000000006
23609 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365713] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: ffff9015bda178c0
23610 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365714] RBP: ffffb77bc2c0fc30 R08: 00000000000002a5 R09: 0000000000000004
23611 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365714] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9015b3668045
23612 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365715] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffff9015b3668075 R15: 0000000000000000
23613 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365715] FS:  00007fad0446fcc0(0000) GS:ffff9015bda00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
23614 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365716] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
23615 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365717] CR2: 00007f5a90143000 CR3: 00000000733e8003 CR4: 00000000000606f0
23616 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365719] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
23617 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365720] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
23618 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365720] Call Trace:
23619 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365725]  __check_heap_object+0xb1/0x120
23620 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365726]  __check_object_size+0x13f/0x150
23621 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365728]  simple_copy_to_iter+0x2b/0x50
23622 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365730]  __skb_datagram_iter+0x19d/0x2d0
23623 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365731]  ? __skb_wait_for_more_packets+0x170/0x170
23624 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365732]  skb_copy_datagram_iter+0x40/0x90
23625 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365734]  tun_do_read+0x48e/0x680
23626 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365751]  ? wake_up_q+0x70/0x70
23627 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365753]  tun_chr_read_iter+0x5b/0xa0
23628 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365755]  new_sync_read+0x122/0x1b0
23629 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365757]  __vfs_read+0x29/0x40
23630 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365758]  vfs_read+0xab/0x160
23631 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365771]  ksys_read+0x67/0xe0
23632 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365772]  __x64_sys_read+0x1a/0x20
23633 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365774]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
23634 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365776]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
23635 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365777] RIP: 0033:0x7fad04c2e332
23636 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365778] Code: 9c 00 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb be 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 56 c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 48>
23637 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365779] RSP: 002b:00007ffd1079e418 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
23638 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365780] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffd1079e470 RCX: 00007fad04c2e332
23639 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365780] RDX: 00000000000005fc RSI: 000055f8cbde5948 RDI: 0000000000000004
23640 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365791] RBP: 00007ffd1079e470 R08: 00000000000005fc R09: 000000000000000a
23641 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365792] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000002
23642 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365792] R13: 000055f8cab79540 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
23643 Jul  2 13:53:08 ubuntuserver kernel: [ 2195.365794] ---[ end trace 450a76c5d79c77ee ]---

24934 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809863] ------------[ cut here ]------------
24935 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809865] Bad or missing usercopy whitelist? Kernel memory exposure attempt detected from SLUB object 'mnt_cache' (offset 143, size 2)!
24936 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809872] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 11965 at mm/usercopy.c:75 usercopy_warn+0x81/0xa0
24937 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809873] Modules linked in: xt_statistic vxlan ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel xt_set ipt_rpfilter xt_multiport iptable_raw ip_set_hash_ip ip_set_hash_net ip_set veth xt_nat xt_tcpudp xt_mark i>
24938 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809901]  raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel vmwgfx aesni_intel ttm drm_kms_helper crypto_simd syscopyarea cryptd sysfillrec>
24939 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809939] CPU: 3 PID: 11965 Comm: openvpn Tainted: G           O      5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu
24940 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809940] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
24941 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809941] RIP: 0010:usercopy_warn+0x81/0xa0
24942 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809942] Code: 58 9a 41 51 49 89 c0 49 c7 c2 19 47 57 9a 49 89 f1 48 89 f9 4c 0f 45 d2 48 c7 c7 08 7a 58 9a 4c 89 da 4c 89 d6 e8 b1 b1 7b 00 <0f> 0b 48 83 c4 18 c9 c3 48 c7 c6 ba 8e 5a 9a>
24943 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809943] RSP: 0018:ffffa4e60806fc18 EFLAGS: 00010286
24944 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809944] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 0000000000000006
24945 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809944] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: ffff964ffdb978c0
24946 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809945] RBP: ffffa4e60806fc30 R08: 00000000000002b3 R09: 0000000000000004
24947 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809945] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff964fba0381cf
24948 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809946] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffff964fba0381d1 R15: 0000000000000000
24949 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809947] FS:  00007feb9eea0cc0(0000) GS:ffff964ffdb80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
24950 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809948] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
24951 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809948] CR2: 00007fdc5304332c CR3: 000000007123e003 CR4: 00000000000606e0
24952 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809951] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
24953 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809951] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
24954 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809952] Call Trace:
24955 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809955]  __check_heap_object+0xb1/0x120
24956 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809956]  __check_object_size+0x13f/0x150
24957 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809958]  simple_copy_to_iter+0x2b/0x50
24958 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809960]  __skb_datagram_iter+0x19d/0x2d0
24959 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809961]  ? __skb_wait_for_more_packets+0x170/0x170
24960 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809962]  skb_copy_datagram_iter+0x40/0x90
24961 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809964]  tun_do_read+0x48e/0x680
24962 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809966]  ? wake_up_q+0x70/0x70
24963 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809967]  tun_chr_read_iter+0x5b/0xa0
24964 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809969]  new_sync_read+0x122/0x1b0
24965 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809985]  __vfs_read+0x29/0x40
24966 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809986]  vfs_read+0xab/0x160
24967 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809987]  ksys_read+0x67/0xe0
24968 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809989]  __x64_sys_read+0x1a/0x20
24969 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809991]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
24970 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809992]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
24971 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809993] RIP: 0033:0x7feb9f65f332
24972 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809994] Code: 9c 00 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb be 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 56 c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 48>
24973 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809995] RSP: 002b:00007ffd7ea61018 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
24974 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809996] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffd7ea61070 RCX: 00007feb9f65f332
24975 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809996] RDX: 00000000000005fc RSI: 00005626cf1a9948 RDI: 0000000000000004
24976 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809997] RBP: 00007ffd7ea61070 R08: 00000000000005fc R09: 000000000000000a
24977 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809997] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000002
24978 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.809998] R13: 00005626cdae3540 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
24979 Jul  2 14:58:13 ubuntuserver kernel: [  319.810000] ---[ end trace 29288b72c43a7e01 ]---
```

Comment: The `Kernel memory exposure attempt detected from SLUB object 'mnt_cache'` points to something directly manipulating what is stored in memory, risking kernel-space data being exposed to the user space, which can then result in passwords or encryption keys being exposed to anything and everything on the server. Aside from the Torrent stuff, is there anything else running on the VM that might want direct access to system memory? 

Comment: mh, I am not sure the only programs I installed that are running are: rtorrent, apache, irssi, screen and openvpn :/ Should I just setup a new VM? It could be that I messed some files up as this is my first linux server setup

Answer (score 0):

I think I've been able to solve this by removing microK8s and rebuilding guest additions from the iso. Machine seems to be running smooth now, not sure if it was microk8s package or a faulty guest additions install, but hopefully it might help someone with a similar problem in the future :)